# Android active DnD when listening to bluetooth music in car

Tags: android-13, do-not-disturb

I'm on Android 13.The issue I'm having seems to have started after the last security updates. I listen to Spotify in my car. Now I see that DnD is turned on when the car is connected via bluetooth to my phone (Pixel 4a). The car does not have Android Auto. It is an older Mazda 3 from 2010.
I have looked at the settings in Spotify and the phone, but cannot see anything that could prevent this from happening.
Even if I manually turn off DnD, it sometimes gets activated again later. Very annoying.
Any suggesting of what to do?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Have you checked the Do Not Disturb setting on the phone, particularly under Schedules - Driving - Turn on automatically? It has "When connected to Bluetooth" and "When driving is detected" as some of the triggers.